# Confirmación personalizada al cerrar una pestaña javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas tardes a todos.

Tengo una inquietud, deseo lanzar un mensaje de confirmación al usuario cuando este quiera cerrar la pestaña del navegador. Sé (por muchos otros posts) que la mayoría recomienda usar onbeforeunload. Por ejemplo, con este código:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(t){ 
        t.returnValue="Saliendo..";
        return confirm("Seguro deseas salir?")
    };
```

En el navegador sale

[image: Cuadro de confirmación]

Como ven, no veo por ningun lado los mensajes que estaban en la funcion añadida anteriormente. Mi pregunta es: no existe otro modo de hacerlo, es decir, no puedo yo crear una confirmación personalizada?? Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas agregar el `confirm`.  Intentalo asi:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){         
    return "Seguro deseas salir?";
};
```

Comment: Jejeje gracias por responder. Aun haciendo esto, dicho String que se envia en el return no sale en el mensaje de confirmación (como lo adjunte en la imagen). Por eso deseo saber si existe otra forma